# MciSendString automatically plays AVI files at fullspeed

Tags: c++, mcisendstring

I'm trying to play avi files with mciSendString.

Here's my testing code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    mciSendString("open D:\\something.avi type avivideo alias myAlias", NULL, 0, NULL);

    mciSendString("play myAlias fullscreen from 0", NULL, 0, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is it plays the file at fullspeed, as if I had done :

```
mciSendString("set myAlias speed 0", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

I tried to set the speed to 1000, to no avail.

Some weird things :

- If I set the speed to 2000 for example, the file does play at double speed instead of fullspeed
- For some files, it is displayed at normal speed and I can't seem to figure out why.

I tried to find out where it comes from with GSpot (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSpot) because I already had this software for previous reasons but I couldn't find any correlation.

Please understand that my knowledge in media files is close to nonexistent, so try keeping it as simple as possible.

Thank you.